# Cancel Firebase redirect

Tags: firebase, redirect, firebase-hosting

I redirected my firebase landing page by editing the firebase.json file:

```
"redirects": [ {
  "source": "/",
  "destination": "https://subdomain.mydomain.com/maintenance/",
  "type": 301
} ]
```

Now I want to revert back so that when someone enters "https://subdomain.mydomain.com" they're taken to "https://subdomain.mydomain.com/index.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question/problem. Did you make the change you want to `firebase.json` and then apply it by running  `firebase deploy`?

Comment: Yes, I changed my firebase.json file so that it redirected to https://subdomain.mydomain.com/maintenance/index.html; then I deployed it. Of course it did what it was suppose to do: if I enter "https://subdomain.mydomain.com" in a browser it will go to "https://subdomain.mydomain.com/maintenance/index.html" but now I don't want it to do that anymore.

Comment: So how about removing that redirect from your `firebase.json` and deploying that update?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Frank. The solution was to remove the redirect code from the file; deploy, and ensure the cache was cleared.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned to Frank, the solution was to remove the redirect code from the file; deploy, and ensure the cache was cleared. If you don't clear your cache you'll be tricked into thinking your firebase.json file isn't working and the re-direct is still being applied...that is not the case! Simply clear your cache after deploying firebase.json without the redirect code and voila, you're back to root index of your site.